# Advice on building a gaming/web development rig

Tags: gaming, desktop, web-development

I have pretty much no experience or knowledge about modern hardware, other than the past couple hours I've spent researching it.

I built a rig online here:
http://pcpartpicker.com/list/BwmgLD

I was hoping for any advice/recommendations.  Anything that I'm paying too much for, that I wouldn't notice a difference with a cheaper option.  Anything that I'm potentially bottlenecking my setup by going too cheap.  Any brand that I chose that is know for being unreliable.  Etc.

There are a couple notes on compatibility shown, it seems like they wouldn't be problems for me but if you think it will let me know.

I especially know nothing about what makes a case good or bad, and what is necessary with the power supply.

I have never put a rig together before, I do have experience soldering from my EE degree.  I don't even know if you have to solder stuff together, but if the case influences the ease of assembly let me know.

I already have a ergodox keyboard. I have heard a gaming mouse isn't really any better than a normal one.  And I plan to have a triple monitor set up eventually.

I prefer to develop on linux, but I figured for gaming I'll need to get windows and maybe run linux on a vm.

The price is about where I'd like it, maybe a bit cheaper if possible.  But working on this computer is going to be my livelihood so I can spend some more if necessary.

And just any general advice for someone trying to build a rig for the first time would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately this is both too broad and off-topic. We can't do general advice, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why do you need a wired network card, the mobo has Ethernet built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaming generally benefits from faster single core but VM benefits from multiple cores. If you are planning to run less than 4 ish VMs then the i5 6500K will be a better choice (of course you will have to change your motherboard as well).

That SSD is cheap, a little too cheap. Go with some reputable brand to get performance and quality (such as Samsung, AData, Patriot, Sandisk, etc.). You could also take a look at having a smaller SSD for boot and a hard drive for your games and other files.

Your motherboard comes with an ethernet port so unless you are going to use multiple IPs or aggregate the connection you don't need the ethernet card. Your motherboard is a mATX motherboard, which is smaller than the regular ATX size. This fits in your case but you lose the extra PCIe ports you could get from an ATX board.

You might also want to take a look at a CPU cooler like the Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo (bare minimum) because the CPU runs quite hot and the stock cooler isn't that great.

Everything else looks fine, GPU is powerful enough and PSU delivers enough wattage.